# Material UI form elements have transparent black color that I can't get rid of

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

I'm trying to make a form for my Next.js side project using the Material UI components, but there are some styles being applied to the MUI components that I can't find the source of, and can't figure out how to override.

To make my form, I copied & pasted the exact code from the [Radio group](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-radio-button/#radio-group) and [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/#basic-select) examples in the MUI documentation, but they weren't showing up on my black background. Eventually I figured out that the color of the Selector and Radio buttons was being set to a semi-transparent black.

I didn't set that color myself, and I don't see it being applied to any of the components on the Material UI documentation site. The classes that are giving those styles are `.css-hfutr2-MuiSvgIcon-root-MuiSelect-icon`, `.css-3zljrz-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root`, as well as others. The classes seem to have different alpha values for the black color.

[A picture of the styles being applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTS5q.png)

After failing to find the source of the transparent black styles, I started trying to override them. I've tried setting the primary palette color using MUI's `useTheme` hook, but that only changed the styles for when the elements are selected or focused. The elements, in the default state, still had the transparent black color.

I then tried using the `sx` attribute to set the color. I made an object that contained `color: pink`, and passed it to the `sx` attribute of the `FormControl`, `InputLabel`, and `Select` components. The only change from that was that the form label turned pink. Otherwise, the transparent black color was still being applied to the down arrow svg and the outline of the select.

My ideal scenario would be figuring out how the transparent black is being applied and how to get rid of it. I don't really want to do a jank workaround I'm hoping that I just missed something and this will be an easy fix, but I've spent way too much time staring at this. Thank you :)

Here's the file where I'm creating the form:

```
interface Props {
  questionText: string
  options: string[]
  value: string | undefined
  setValue: Function
}

const formStyles = { // To be used as the sx attribute
  color: pink[800],
}

export function NewCharacterFormQuestion({questionText, options, value, setValue}: Props) {
  const selectorOptions = options.map(option => {
    return (
      <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>{option}</MenuItem>
    )
  })

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120, ...formStyles }}>
        <InputLabel id="select-label" sx={formStyles}>Race</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="select-label"
          id="simple-select"
          value={value}
          label="Race"
          autoWidth
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          sx={formStyles}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">Unspecified</MenuItem>
          {selectorOptions}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  )
}
```

The file where I create the MUI theme:

```
import { deepOrange, pink } from '@mui/material/colors';
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const muiTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: pink,
    secondary: deepOrange
  },
});
```

Where I apply the theme in the Next.js default layout (`app/layout.tsx`):

```
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>My page title</title>
      </head>

      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
          <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
            <div className="z-10 max-w-5xl w-full items-center justify-between font-mono text-sm lg:flex">
              {children}
            </div>
          </main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be easier for you to start by installing dark mode:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';

const darkTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: 'dark',
  },
});

...
<ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
  <CssBaseline />
  ...
</ThemeProvider>
```

Details about dark mode:
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/dark-mode/